# eglCreateImage vs eglCreateImageKHR

Tags: c++, opengl-es, egl

I'm trying to compile a [gbm egl example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/drm-tests/+/bc4d0a01766ae7450554ca11610a00d044c132e7/null_platform_test.c) but my EGL library doesn't have the `eglCreateImageKHR` symbols defined.  Can i swap these out for `eglCreateImage`?  What are the differences between these two functions?